# How do I implement the Chain of Responsibility pattern using a chain of trait objects?

Tags: design-patterns, rust, chain-of-responsibility

I'm trying to implement the Chain of Responsibility design pattern in Rust:

```
pub trait Policeman<'a> {
    fn set_next(&'a mut self, next: &'a Policeman<'a>);
}

pub struct Officer<'a> {
    deduction: u8,
    next: Option<&'a Policeman<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Officer<'a> {
    pub fn new(deduction: u8) -> Officer<'a> {
        Officer {deduction, next: None}
    }
}

impl<'a> Policeman<'a> for Officer<'a> {
    fn set_next(&'a mut self, next: &'a Policeman<'a>) {
        self.next = Some(next);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vincent = Officer::new(8);    // -+ vincent enters the scope
    let mut john = Officer::new(5);   // -+ john enters the scope
    let mut martin = Officer::new(3); // -+ martin enters the scope
                                      //  |
    john.set_next(&vincent);          //  |
    martin.set_next(&john);           //  |
}                                     // martin, john, vincent out of scope
```

This produces the error message:

```
error[E0597]: `john` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:29:1
   |
27 |     john.set_next(&vincent);
   |     ---- borrow occurs here
28 |     martin.set_next(&john);
29 | }
   | ^ `john` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created

error[E0597]: `martin` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:29:1
   |
28 |     martin.set_next(&john);
   |     ------ borrow occurs here
29 | }
   | ^ `martin` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created

error[E0597]: `john` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:29:1
   |
28 |     martin.set_next(&john);
   |                      ---- borrow occurs here
29 | }
   | ^ `john` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

Why does `john` not live long enough?

1. Created `vincent`
2. Created `john`
3. Created `martin`
4. `john` refers to `vincent` (`vincent` in scope)
5. `martin` refers to `john (john` in scope)
6. `martin` out of scope (`john` still in scope)
7. `john` out of scope (`vincent` still in scope)
8. `vincent` out of scope

How do I need to change the lifetimes or the code to correctly implement the Chain of Responsibility pattern in Rust?

Comment: I think that questions like "how do I implement pattern X in Rust" are hard to answer. "How do I solve problem X" is better.

Comment: <paperclip voice>It looks like you're trying to make a linked list in Rust. Have you read [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/)?</paperclip voice>

Comment: No. I'll start reading right now.

Comment: No solution for the whole question but a reminder that if you use the same **lifetime parameter** in multiple locations in an item, you're creating a restriction: the compiler must find a concrete lifetime that satisfies all three locations simultaneously. This is most often not what you want, it's too restrictive.

Comment: @trentcl Beautiful text, excellent humor! Thanks for the link.

Comment: @user4815162342 It is very good. I was skimming it again today and realized that there are some corners where it is out of date; for example, you don't need nightly for `Rc::try_unwrap` anymore, as that was stabilized in 1.4.0. By and large it is still a good introduction to many common patterns in Rust.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Detailed explanation

Your problem is quite interesting and it's certainly hard to understand directly why it doesn't work. It helps a lot if you understand how the compiler does unification. We will walk through all steps the compiler does in order to find out types.

In order to make it a bit easier, we use this simplified example:

```
let vincent = Officer::new(8);
let mut john = Officer::new(5);

john.set_next(&vincent);
```

This results in the same error message:

```
error[E0597]: `john` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:26:1
   |
25 |     john.set_next(&vincent);
   |     ---- borrow occurs here
26 | }  
   | ^ `john` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

First, let's transform the code in a form that's more explicit, lifetime wise:

```
{ // start 'v
    let vincent = Officer::new(8);   

    { // start 'j
        let mut john = Officer::new(5);  

        john.set_next(&vincent);    
    } // end 'j
} // end 'v
```

---

Ok, now we're prepared to see what the compiler is thinking, step by step:

> ```
> { // start 'v
>     let vincent = Officer::new(8); // : Officer<'?arg_vincent>
> ```

Rust doesn't know the lifetime parameter yet, thus it can only deduce an incomplete type here. Hopefully we can fill out the details later! When the compiler wants to show missing type information, it prints an underscore (e.g. `Vec<_>`). In this example I've written the missing information as `'?arg_vincent`. That way we can refer to it later.

> ```
>     { // start 'j
>         let mut john = Officer::new(5); // : Officer<'?arg_john>
> ```

The same as above.

> ```
>         john.set_next(&vincent);
> ```

Now it get's interesting! The compiler has this function signature:

```
fn set_next(&'a mut self, next: &'a Policeman<'a>)
```

Now, the compiler's job is to find a fitting lifetime `'a` that satisfies a bunch of conditions:

- We have `&'a mut self` and `john` is `self` here. So `'a` can't live longer than `john`. In other words: `'j` *outlives* `'a`, denoted `'j: 'a`.
- We have `next: &'a ...` and `next` is `vincent`, so (just like above), `'a` can't live longer than `vincent`. `'v` *outlives* `'a` => 'v: 'a`.
- Lastly, the `'a` in `Policeman<'a>` refers to the (yet to be determined) lifetime parameter `'?arg_vincent` (since that's what we pass as argument). But `'?arg_vincent` is not yet fixed and totally unbounded. So this doesn't impose a restriction on `'a` (unlike the previous two points). Instead, our choice for `'a` determines`'?arg_vincent` later: `'?arg_vincent := 'a`.

So in short:

```
'j: 'a    and
'v: 'a
```

So what's a lifetime which lives at most as long as john **and** as most as long as vincent? `'v` isn't sufficient, since it outlives `john`. `'j` is fine; it satisfied the conditions above.

So everything is fine? No! We chose the lifetime `'a = 'j` now. Thus we also know that `'?arg_vincent = 'j`! So the full type of `vincent` is `Officer<'j>`. This in turn tells the compiler that `vincent` borrowed something with the lifetime `j`. But `vincent` lives longer than `'j`, so it outlives its borrow! That's bad. That's why the compiler complains.

This whole thing is really rather complex, and I guess that after reading my explanation, most people feel exactly like I feel after reading most math proofs: each step made sense, but the result isn't intuitive. *Maybe* this improves the situation slightly:

Since the `set_next()` function requires all lifetimes to *be* `'a`, we impose a lot of restrictions on all lifetimes in our program. This quickly leads to contradictions in restrictions, as it happened here.

#### A quick fix for my small example

... is to remove the `'a` from the `self` parameter:

```
fn set_next(&mut self, next: &'a Policeman<'a>)
```

By doing that we remove unnecessary restrictions. Unfortunately, this isn't enough to make your whole example compile.

### A more general solution

I'm not very familiar with the design pattern you mentions, but from the looks of it, it's close to impossible to track the involved lifetimes at compile time. Thus I'd use `Rc` or `Arc` instead of references. With those smartpointers, you don't need to annotate lifetimes and everything "just works". Only disadvantage: a tiny bit of runtime cost.

But it's impossible to tell you the best solution: it really depends on the problem at hand.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. `So everything is fine? No! We chose the lifetime 'a = 'j now.` I thought that `'a >= 'j`

Comment: @ArkadiyKuznetsov What exactly do you mean by `'a >= 'j`? Anyway, I don't see the problem in what you said. But I might be confused again :P

Comment: I thought that compiller khows all lifetimes and just checks the code.  
`vincent` is `Officer<'v>, `john` is `Officer<'j'>`.  
When I call `john.set_next(&vincent)` compiller just checks that `'v >= 'j`.

Comment: @ArkadiyKuznetsov Well, the compiler tries to find out all the lifetimes, yes! That's the process I described in my answer. It's not (necessarily) true that `vincent` is `Officer<'v>` and `john` is `Officer<'j>`. Those lifetime parameters are determined by other things (as described in the answer).

Comment: Thank you for that. I see my mistake.

Answer (score 9):

[Lukas's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46744771/3650362) explains why this won't work and you should consider using smart pointers -- either `Box` for single ownership, or `Rc`/`Arc` for shared ownership.

That said, you can do something similar (although not very useful) by getting rid of the `Policeman` trait and making `set_next` inherent to `Officer`:

```
pub struct Officer<'a> {
    deduction: u8,
    next: Option<&'a Officer<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Officer<'a> {
    pub fn new(deduction: u8) -> Officer<'a> {
        Officer {deduction, next: None}
    }
    fn set_next(&mut self, next: &'a Officer<'a>) {
        self.next = Some(next);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vincent = Officer::new(8);    // -+ vincent enters the scope
    let mut john = Officer::new(5);   // -+ john enters the scope
    let mut martin = Officer::new(3); // -+ martin enters the scope
                                      //  |
    john.set_next(&vincent);          //  |
    martin.set_next(&john);           //  |
}                                     // martin, john, vincent out of scope
```

This works ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=85c307be12b4be680fbbcbd5bbfbaa64&version=stable)) because the struct `Officer` is [covariant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance) with respect to `'a`. That means that if you have an `Officer<'a>`, you can treat it like an `Officer<'b>` as long as `'a: 'b`; that is, when `'a` outlives `'b`, `Officer<'a>` is a *subtype* of `Officer<'b>`. This knowledge lets the compiler shrink the lifetimes of each reference in the way you probably expected at first. (There's another [really good Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637911/how-can-this-instance-seemingly-outlive-its-own-parameter-lifetime) about variance that you may enjoy, although it doesn't quite apply to your situation.)

[Traits, on the other hand, are always *in*variant with respect to their parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946525/why-do-the-lifetimes-on-a-trait-object-passed-as-an-argument-require-higher-rank), so `Policeman<'a>` is *not* a subtype of `Policeman<'b>`. This robs the compiler of the ability to adjust lifetimes: the reference `&'_ john` could perhaps have a shorter lifetime, but the `Policeman<'_>` trait can't. That's why even Lukas's "quick fix" won't work on your whole example.

There's at least one more way to make the original example work by adding a lifetime parameter so that `set_next` doesn't unify the two lifetimes in `&'?first Policeman<'?second>`, but from that change you get only one extra layer of indirection -- i.e., it would make the example work, but if you added `michael` who reports to `martin`, you'd be back where you started.