# Why do the lifetimes on a trait object passed as an argument require Higher Ranked Trait Bounds but a struct doesn't?

Tags: rust, lifetime

How are lifetimes handled when there is a trait object passed to a function?

```
struct Planet<T> {
    i: T,
}

trait Spinner<T> {
    fn spin(&self, value: T);
}

impl<T> Spinner<T> for Planet<T> {
    fn spin(&self, value: T) {}
}

// foo2 fails: Due to lifetime of local variable being less than 'a
fn foo2<'a>(t: &'a Spinner<&'a i32>) {
    let x: i32 = 10;
    t.spin(&x);
}

// foo1 passes: But here also the lifetime of local variable is less than 'a?
fn foo1<'a>(t: &'a Planet<&'a i32>) {
    let x: i32 = 10;
    t.spin(&x);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=933db03230161c21356523d67e8ec313&version=stable&mode=debug))

This code results in this error:

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:16:17
   |
16 |         t.spin(&x);
   |                 ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
17 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 14:5...
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     fn foo2<'a>(t: &'a Spinner<&'a i32>) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The function signature of `foo1` is nearly same as `foo2`. One receiving the reference to *struct* and the other a *trait object*.

I read this is where Higher Ranked Trait Bounds comes in. Modifying *foo2* as `foo2(t: &for<'a> Spinner<&'a i32>)` compiles the code, but I don't understand why.

Why won't `'a` shrink for `x`?

Citing [the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html):

> How on earth are we supposed to express the lifetimes on `F`'s trait bound? We need to provide some lifetime there, but the lifetime we care about can't be named until we enter the body of call! Also, that isn't some fixed lifetime; `call` works with any lifetime `&self` happens to have at that point.

Can this please be elaborated?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**In short:** `foo1` compiles because most types are variant over their generic parameters and the compiler can still chose a `Spinner` impl for `t`. `foo2` doesn't compile because traits are invariant over their generic parameters and the `Spinner` impl is already fixed.

---

#### Some explanation

Let's take a look at a third version of `foo`:

```
fn foo3<'a>(t: &'a Planet<&'a i32>) {
    let x: i32 = 10;
    Spinner::<&'a i32>::spin(t, &x);
}
```

This results in the same error as your `foo2`. What's going in there?

By writing `Spinner::<&'a i32>::spin`, we force the compiler to use a specific implementation of the `Spinner` trait. And the signature of `Spinner::<&'a i32>::spin` is `fn spin(&self, value: &'a i32)`. Period. The lifetime `'a` is given by the caller; `foo` can't choose it. Thus we have to pass a reference that lives for at least `'a`. That's why the compiler error happens.

---

So **why does `foo1` compile?** As a reminder:

```
fn foo1<'a>(t: &'a Planet<&'a i32>) {
    let x: i32 = 10;
    t.spin(&x);
}
```

Here, the lifetime `'a` is also given by the caller and cannot be chosen by `foo1`. *But*, `foo1` can chose which impl of `Spinner` to use! Note that `impl<T> Spinner<T> for Planet<T>` basically defines infinitely many specific implementations (one for each `T`). So the compiler also knows that `Planet<&'x i32>` does implement `Spinner<&'x i32>` (where `'x` is the specific lifetime of `x` in the function)!

Now the compiler just has to figure out if it can turn `Planet<&'a i32>` into `Planet<&'x i32>`. And yes, it can, because [most types are variant over their generic parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) and thus `Planet<&'a i32>` is a subtype of `Planet<&'x i32>` if `'a` is a subtype of `'x` (which it is). So the compiler just "converts" `t` to `Planet<&'x i32>` and then the `Spinner<&'x i32>` impl can be used.

---

Fantastic! But now to the main part: **why doesn't `foo2` compile then?** Again, as a reminder:

```
fn foo2<'a>(t: &'a Spinner<&'a i32>) {
    let x: i32 = 10;
    t.spin(&x);
}
```

Again, `'a` is given by the caller and `foo2` cannot chose it. Unfortunately, now we already have a specific implementation! Namely `Spinner<&'a i32>`. We can't just assume that the thing we were passed also implements `Spinner<&'o i32>` for any other lifetime `'o != 'a`! [Traits are invariant over their generic parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html).

In other words: we know we have *something* that can handle references which live at least as long as `'a`. But we can't assume that the thing we were handed can also handle lifetimes shorter than `'a`!

As an example:

```
struct Star;

impl Spinner<&'static i32> for Star {
    fn spin(&self, value: &'static i32) {}
}

static SUN: Star = Star;

foo2(&SUN);
```

In this example, `'a` of `foo2` is `'static`. And in fact, `Star` implements `Spinner` only for `'static` references to `i32`.

---

By the way: **this is not specific to trait objects!** Let's look at this fourth version of `foo`:

```
fn foo4<'a, S: Spinner<&'a i32>>(t: &'a S) {
    let x: i32 = 10;
    t.spin(&x);
}
```

Same error once again. The problem is, again, that the `Spinner` impl is already fixed! As with the trait object, we only know that `S` implements `Spinner<&'a i32>`, not necessarily more.

#### HRTB to the rescue?

Using higher ranked trait bounds resolves the issue:

```
fn foo2(t: &for<'a> Spinner<&'a i32>)
```

and

```
fn foo4<S: for<'a> Spinner<&'a i32>>(t: &S)
```

As it's hopefully clear from the explanation above, this works because we the specific impl of `Spinner` isn't fixed anymore! Instead, we again have infinitely many impls to choose from (one for each `'a`). Thus we can choose the impl where `'a == 'x`.

Comment: Thanks! That was very insightful.