# Lifetime sub-typing and impl-trait

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, existential-type

I bumped into an interesting form of lifetime sub-typing, which I think is valid, but the compiler is skeptical of.

Consider the following function, which computes the dot-product of two sequences of references.

```rust
fn dot_prod<'a>(xs: impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a usize>, ys: impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a usize>) -> usize {
    let mut acc = 0;
    for (x, y) in xs.into_iter().zip(ys.into_iter()) {
        acc += *x * *y;
    }
    acc
}
```

The signature ascribes the same lifetime to the references in both sequences. The "a single lifetime for both inputs" pattern is common, because sub-typing allows the function to be used on references of different lifetimes. However, something here (perhaps `impl trait`?) blocks this. Let's look at a example of a blocked use (playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6a3051b69090e1370f3ed90193392bc)):

```rust
fn dot_prod_wrap<'a>(xs: impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a usize>, ys: impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a usize>) -> usize {
    let xs: Vec<usize> = xs.into_iter().cloned().collect();
    let ys = ys.into_iter();
    dot_prod(&xs, ys)
}
```

Rustc rejects this, observing that the local `xs` is not valid for `'a`, from which we can infer that it has plugged in `'a` for the function call's lifetime parameter. However, I think this should type-check, by plugging in the local scope's lifetime (call it `'b`), and deducing that `ys` has a type which is a sub-typed of something that implements `IntoIterator<Item = &'b usize>`, where `'b` is the local scope.

A few variations of this do work, such as [changing the impl traits to slices](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a7d3caabd103b435b08c45fe0596144) and [using two lifetime paramters](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=32f6b70988a53dd54e4f0fd40c61215d), but I'm curious about there is a way of getting the Rust compiler to accept a wapper like `dot_prod_wrap` without changing the signature of `dot_prod`.

I'm also aware that both sub-typing and `impl trait` are complex, so perhaps the validity argument I'm presenting above is wrong. The claim "`ys` has a type which is a sub-typed of something that implements `IntoIterator<Item = &'b usize>`" is particularly suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Traits are invariant over their generic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946525/why-do-the-lifetimes-on-a-trait-object-passed-as-an-argument-require-higher-rank). Once the borrow checker has deduced `impl IntoIterator<Item = &'a usize>` a proper lifetime `'a` it cannot be changed, not even to a shorter lifetime.

The reason is because trait objects are black boxes; they can do anything they want within the bounds of their constraints. This includes things like *iterior mutability* which cannot use a shorter lifetime (otherwise you'd be able to assign a value with a shorter lifetime to an object expecting a longer one). It works for slices because the borrow checker knows the lifetime is covariant; so it can be made shorter when required.

You should make `dot_prod` use two independent lifetimes.

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm curious about there is a way of getting the Rust compiler to accept a wapper like `dot_prod_wrap` without changing the signature of `dot_prod`.

[kmdreko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67205205/5223757) is correct about the reasons Rust behaves this way: knowing only that `ys`'s `IntoIterator::IntoIter` type has a certain lifetime isn't enough for it to know whether it can shorten that lifetime. *However*, that `Iterator<Item=&'a usize>` isn't an opaque black box to us programmers:

```
let ys = ys.into_iter().map(|y| y);
```

By mapping all the values in the iterator to themselves, we allow Rust to pick an appropriate return type for the closure. After a bit of thinking, `rustc` determines that in order to make the `dot_prod` call type check, it needs to shorten the lifetime of the returned borrow to match `xs`.

`.map(|y| y)` doesn't *do* anything beyond the type system, so `rustc` will optimise it out entirely in release builds. (It can do this in all circumstances, since this closure is a zero-sized opaque type. I'm not entirely sure it *does* in all circumstances, but I can't think of a reason it wouldn't.)