# Lifetime in recursive struct with mutable reference

Tags: rust, lifetime, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to define a recursive struct similar to a linked list for a tree traversal. A node has some data and access to its parent. The child node should borrow its parent mutably to ensure exclusive access, and release it once it's dropped. I can define this struct using immutable references, but not when I make the parent reference mutable. When making the parent reference mutable, I am confused by the compiler error and do not understand it.

How can I define the lifetimes for such a recursive structure with a mutable parent reference?

Here is a minimal example. This compiles but uses a readonly reference:

```
struct Node<'a> {
    // Parent reference. `None` indicates a root node.
    // I want this to be a mutable reference.
    pub parent: Option<&'a Node<'a>>,
    // This field just represents some data attached to this node.
    pub value: u32,
}

// Creates a root node
// I use a static lifetime since there's no parent for the root so there are no constraints there
fn root_node(value: u32) -> Node<'static> {
    Node {
        parent: None,
        value,
    }
}

// Creates a child node
// The lifetimes indicates that the parent must outlive its child
fn child_node<'inner, 'outer: 'inner>(
    parent: &'inner mut Node<'outer>,
    value: u32,
) -> Node<'inner> {
    Node {
        parent: Some(parent),
        value,
    }
}

// An example function using the struct
fn main() {
    let mut root = root_node(0);
    let mut c1 = child_node(&mut root, 1);
    let mut c2 = child_node(&mut c1, 2);
    {
        let mut c3 = child_node(&mut c2, 3);
        let c4 = child_node(&mut c3, 4);
        let mut cur = Some(&c4);
        while let Some(n) = cur {
            println!("{}", n.value);
            cur = n.parent;
        }
    }
    {
        let c5 = child_node(&mut c2, 5);
        let mut cur = Some(&c5);
        while let Some(n) = cur {
            println!("{}", n.value);
            cur = n.parent;
        }
    }
    println!("{}", c2.value);
}
```

[Rust playground: immutable reference](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=89d85e51d29638170b5eb7201198c28d)

I want a mutable reference, so I tried to replace the `Node` struct to use a mutable reference:

```
struct Node<'a> {
    // Parent reference. `None` indicates a root node.
    // I want this to be a mutable reference.
    pub parent: Option<&'a mut Node<'a>>,
    // This field just represents some data attached to this node.
    pub value: u32,
}
```

But then I get the following error:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
  --> src/main.rs:25:22
   |
21 |     parent: &'inner mut Node<'outer>,
   |             ------------------------
   |             |
   |             these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
...
25 |         parent: Some(parent),
   |                      ^^^^^^ ...but data from `parent` flows into `parent` here
```

[Rust playground: mutable reference](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=889d92c73a45a527feb932d3dbaefbce)

I do not understand the relationship between mutability and data flowing into a field. In the immutable case, I was already requiring the functions to pass mutable/exclusive references. I've been trying various combinations of lifetimes (using a single lifetime, reversing their relationship, etc.) but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Pretty sure that your entire concept is flawed. This structure would allow mutable aliasing (`head.next.next` and `(head.next).next`).

Comment: @Shepmaster My goal is that only the lowest (active) node can manipulate the data in the chain. I do not quite understand your notation for mutable aliasing. In my example, once `c3` is created it borrows `c2` (and with it `c1` and `root`) so you can't access those until `c2` is dropped and so you shouldn't be able to alias them (at least it's the goal).

Comment: This strongly reminds me of [How do I implement the Chain of Responsibility pattern using a chain of trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46743353/3650362), but I'm not sure it is close enough to mark a duplicate. Do the answers to that question (both mine and Lukas's) shed any light on your problem?

Comment: @trentcl Thanks, I'll look into it. To give more context, I want to use this structure to pass data between recursive function calls. Each node represents a function call level. This ensures that the parent is created first, I pass it as a mutable reference to the next call, it creates a child node with exclusive access to this parent, and when the inner call ends the child is dropped and I get back access to the parent node.

Comment: @trentcl The question you posted is indeed similar. It's actually a more general question using traits and where the next node is set with a method and not at construction. Your reply to this question actually corresponds to my immutable case. The issue is that I need mutability. Still, I believe that it helped me advance on the problem. I feel like this is related to lifetime variance. I think that I remember that immutable references in structs are covariant but mutable ones are invariant, but I am not sure if it means my question is solvable or not.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to implement this kind of recursive structure with mutable references due to *variance*.

[The Rustonomicon has a section on variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance), with the following table:

```
|           | 'a        | T         |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| &'a T     | covariant | covariant |
| &'a mut T | covariant | invariant |
```

In particular, `&'a mut T` is invariant with regard to `T`.

The core issue here is that a Node only knows the lifetimes of its parent, not the lifetime of all its ancestors. Even if in my case I'm just interested in mutating the `value` field of the ancestor, `&mut Node` also gives access to modify the `parent` field of any ancestor up the chain where we don't have access to the precise lifetime.

Here is an example where my struct may causes unsoundness with a mutable parent reference.
The following code would be accepted if `T` was covariant in `&'a mut T`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut root: Node<'static> = root_node(0);

    // where 'a corresponds to `root`
    let mut c1: Node<'a> = child_node(&mut root, 1);
    {
        let mut evil_root: Node<'static> = root_node(666);
        {
            // where 'b corresponds to `c1`
            let mut c2: Node<'b>  = child_node(&mut c1, 2);
            // where 'c corresponds to `c2`
            let mut c3: Node<'c>  = child_node(&mut c2, 3);

            // Here is the issue: `c3` knows that its ancestors live at least as long
            // as `c2`. But it does not know how long exactly.
            // With covariance, the lifetime of `evil_root` would be compatible since
            // it outlives `c2`. And because `&mut T` enables to mutate any field
            // we could do the following:
            let c2_ref: &mut Node<'c> = c3.parent.unwrap();
            let c1_ref: &mut Node<'c> = c2_ref.parent.unwrap();
            *c1_ref.parent = Some(&mut evil_root);
        }
    }
    // Trying to access the parent of `c1` now causes a read-after-free
    println!("{}", c1.parent.unwrap().value);
}
```

The invariance rule ensures that the code above is rejected by the compiler and there is no unsoundness.

Because `&mut` allows to modify any field, including ones with references, and because this kind of recursion does not keep track of all the parent lifetimes, **it would be unsound**.
To safely implement such a recursive struct Rust would need a reference allowing to mutate `value` (since it has a static lifetime, no issue there) but not `parent`.
In the minimal example I posted above it could be achieved using immutable references for the parents and placing the node data behind a `Cell` or `RefCell`. Another possible solution (but I haven't looked much into it) would be to place the mutable parent references behind a `Pin` but dereferencing it would be `unsafe`: I'd have to manually ensure that I am never changing the `parent` reference.

My actual use case is a bit more complex, so I'll try to instead restructure it to remove the need for the recursive struct by storing my data in a stack backed by a `Vec`.