# What are the differences when getting an immutable reference from a mutable reference with self-linked lifetimes?

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
struct Foo01<'a> {
    val: u32,
    str: &'a String,
}

fn mutate_and_share_01<'a>(foo: &'a mut Foo01<'a>) -> &'a Foo01<'a> {
    foo
}

fn mutate_and_share_02<'a>(foo: &'a mut Foo01<'a>) -> &'a Foo01 {
    foo
}

fn mutate_and_share_03<'a>(foo: &'a mut Foo01) -> &'a Foo01<'a> {
    foo
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo01 { val: 16, str: &String::from("Hello ") };
    let foo_mut = &mut foo;

    //let loan = mutate_and_share_01(foo_mut);
    //let loan2 = mutate_and_share_01(foo_mut); //error

    //let loan = mutate_and_share_02(foo_mut);
    //let loan2 = mutate_and_share_02(foo_mut); //error

    let loan = mutate_and_share_03(foo_mut);
    let loan2 = mutate_and_share_03(foo_mut); //good
}
```

What are differences between these `mutate_and_share` versions?

Comment: In general, the `&'a SomeType<'a>` pattern should be avoided because it usually does not make sense to link the lifetime of a reference to itself like that. And there's a lot of non-obvious problems that can occur ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46743353/2189130) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32165917/2189130) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60177810)) especially when mutable references are involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases 1 and 2, you're saying that the function borrows the structure for as long as the structure borrows its parameter:

> foo: &'a mut Foo01<'a>

this says "foo is borrowed from 'a" (`&'a mut`) and "foo borrows its parameter for `'a`" (`Foo01<'a>`).

Meaning as far as rustc is concerned a call to this function will necessarily borrow the input forever, as the structure necessarily borrows *its* input for the entirety of its own lifetime, and thus you get locked out: you can't "unborrow" the input by dropping it so the second call can't work ever.

In case 3 you're relating the parameter of the *output* to the internal borrow which isn't really true but works well enough at least for this case. The reality is that the two lifetimes are unrelated:

```rust
fn mutate_and_share<'a, 'b>(foo: &'a mut Foo01<'b>) -> &'a Foo01<'b> {
    foo
}
```

Also do note that your third case only works because you're never *using* `loan`, so it's immediately dropped before the second line executes. If you do this:

```rust
    let loan = mutate_and_share_03(foo_mut);
    let loan2 = mutate_and_share_03(foo_mut); //good
    print("{}", loan.val)
```

then it's not going to compile because the mutable borrows are overlapping.

Oh, and `&String` is generally useless. There are use cases for `&mut String`, but any time you see an immutable reference to a `String` you'd be better off with an `&str`. Same with `&Vec<T>`, not useful, should be `&[T]`.

Comment: let foo_mut = &mut foo; // once mut borrow      mutate_and_share_03(foo_mut); //twice mut borrow   why not happen borrow errors

Comment: Because non-lexical borrows: since you're not actually *using* the `loan` variable, the compiler immediately drops it, the borrow ends, and a new one can be created.

Comment: And while you could expect the first call to "move" the mutable reference, Rust will actually implicitly reborrow it in those cases (it's as if you'd written `&mut *foo_mut`), so it actually creates a nested sub-borrow. See [this older answer by Sven Marnach for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62961289/8182118).