# Struct with a mutable reference to another instance of the same type

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

How can I make a struct with an optional mutable reference to it's own type. Not self-referential, so the instance is different, for example

```
struct Environment<'a> {
    outer: Option<&'a mut Environment<'a>>,
    // Can be swapped for any other data
    variables: HashMap<Identifier, Expression>, 
}
```

I've also experimented with:

```
struct Environment<'a, 'b> {
    outer: Option<&'a mut Environment<'b, 'b>>, //...
```

but to no success.

I would like to be able to:

- Keep it as reference (no Box), since the instances would be on stack
- Keep it without extra runtime performance hit (Rc/RefCell)
- Change `variables` in arbitrarily-outer environment
- NOT be able to change the value behind `outer.outer` (as I understand this could lead to unsoundness)
- Keep an inner environment acting as-if it was borrowing the outer environment mutably (exclusively) as long as it exists (so no two inner/children from the same outer/parent)

So a sort of split borrow. Where the `variables` up the `outer` chain are borrowed `&mut`, but `outer` is `&` and the `Environment` as a whole is also `&mut`'d

I understand that the problem is that &mut T is invariant over T. Is there some way I can make `&mut T` become covariant as if it was `&T`?

Edit:
Desired example usage (doesn't compile)

```
struct Environment<'a> {
    outer: Option<&'a mut Environment<'a>>,
    value: i32,
}

impl<'a> Environment<'a> {
    fn new(value: i32) -> Self {
        Self { outer: None, value }
    }
    
    fn child<'b>(&'b mut self, value: i32) -> Environment<'b>
    where
        // This is the relationship I would want
        // parent environment outlives child environment
        'a: 'b
    {
        Self { outer: Some(self), value }
    }
}

fn user_that_creates_child(env: &mut Environment) {
    let child_env = env.child(11);
    // Do something with the child
    child_env.outer.unwrap().value = 8; // This should be possible
    // child_env.outer.unwrap().outer = // This shouldn't be
}

fn main() {
    let mut root_env = Environment::new(7);
}
```

Compiler suggest the inverse of the relationship I want, ie `where 'b: 'a` for the child function

Comment: Can you give a sample of code that you'd like to compile but doesn't?

Comment: @isaactfa Added an example

Comment: This looks increasingly like an intrusively linked list. That's a rather difficult data structure to make sound in Rust. You may want to check if there's an implementation already out there that fits your needs.

Comment: Oh yes you could definitely call it that. I was looking for stack-only intrusive SLL implementations but couldn't find any that fit (a lot of them use Cell or RefCell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't need one lifetime. Even two won't help. You need infinitely many lifetimes, or a dynamic set of lifetimes, to track each dynamic child. This of course can't work.

As far as I know what you want cannot be written in safe Rust.

With unsafe Rust it is possible to do soundly, as long as you never mutate the `outer` pointer. The reason this is not safe is because the compiler cannot prove that. There are two ways to tackle this case with unsafe Rust. One is to store the parent pointer as raw pointer:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::ptr::NonNull;

struct Environment<'a> {
    outer: Option<NonNull<Environment<'a>>>,
    value: HashMap<i32, String>,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

// Needed because of the `NonNull`, safe as long as the keys and values are `Send` and `Sync`.
unsafe impl Send for Environment<'_> {}
unsafe impl Sync for Environment<'_> {}

impl<'a> Environment<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            outer: None,
            value: HashMap::new(),
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    fn child<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Environment<'b> {
        Self {
            outer: Some(self.into()),
            value: HashMap::new(),
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
    
    fn map_depth(&self, depth: u32) -> Option<&HashMap<i32, String>> {
        unsafe {
            let mut this = NonNull::from(self);
            for _ in 0..depth {
                this = this.as_ref().outer?;
            }
            Some(&this.as_ref().value)
        }
    }
    
    fn map_depth_mut(&mut self, depth: u32) -> Option<&mut HashMap<i32, String>> {
        unsafe {
            let mut this = NonNull::from(self);
            for _ in 0..depth {
                this = this.as_mut().outer?;
            }
            Some(&mut this.as_mut().value)
        }
    }
}
```

The other, IMHO more safe, is to use interior mutability: just like wrapping the value in a `RefCell`, just using `UnsafeCell` instead of `RefCell` to avoid runtime overhead:

```rust
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Environment<'a> {
    outer: Option<&'a Environment<'a>>,
    value: UnsafeCell<HashMap<i32, String>>,
}

// Needed because of the `UnsafeCell`, safe as long as the keys and values are `Sync`.
unsafe impl Sync for Environment<'_> {}

impl<'a> Environment<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            outer: None,
            value: UnsafeCell::new(HashMap::new()),
        }
    }

    fn child<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Environment<'b> {
        Environment {
            outer: Some(self),
            value: UnsafeCell::new(HashMap::new()),
        }
    }

    fn map_depth(&self, depth: u32) -> Option<&HashMap<i32, String>> {
        let mut this: &Environment = self;
        for _ in 0..depth {
            this = this.outer?;
        }
        Some(unsafe { &*this.value.get() })
    }

    fn map_depth_mut(&mut self, depth: u32) -> Option<&mut HashMap<i32, String>> {
        let mut this: &Environment = self;
        for _ in 0..depth {
            this = this.outer?;
        }
        Some(unsafe { &mut *this.value.get() })
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted a similar solution I came up with, opted to use UnsafeCell in outer instead so I can extend Environment more easily

Answer (score 1):

I've found a satisfactory-enough answer. First of all, as [@isaactfa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11423104/isaactfa) said, it is an intrusive linked list. I was correct in assuming that the actual issue is with the possibility of assigning a reference to outer with too short a lifetime (good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60179193/2974775)). With that I decided it's okay to use unsafe here.

This is the solution I went with

```
type ScopeMap = HashMap<Identifier, Expression>;

/// A proxy to a locked environment, forming a chain (or an intrusive SLL)
/// Can allow for modifications to any field except the "outer" (the list link)
struct LockedEnvironmentProxy<'a> (
    &'a mut UnsafeCell<Environment<'a>>
);

pub struct Environment<'a> {
    outer: Option<LockedEnvironmentProxy<'a>>,
    variables: ScopeMap,
}

impl<'a> Environment<'a> {
    fn child<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Environment<'b>
    where
        'a: 'b
    {
        Environment { outer: Some(self.into()), variables: Default::default() }
    }
}

impl<'a> LockedEnvironmentProxy<'a> {
    /// Accessing variables mutably from a locked environment
    fn vars_mut(&mut self) -> &mut ScopeMap {
        &mut self.0.get_mut().variables
    }
}

// Deref for ease of use
impl<'a> Deref for LockedEnvironmentProxy<'a> {
    type Target = Environment<'a>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        // SAFETY: Immutable ref into immutable ref
        // this "splits" the borrow into immutable ones
        // UnsafeCell<T> just doesn't have a fn(&self)->&T
        // to do this without unsafe
        unsafe{ &*self.0.get() }
    }
}

impl<'a, 'b> From<&'a mut Environment<'b>> for LockedEnvironmentProxy<'a>
where
    'b: 'a
{
    fn from(value: &'a mut Environment<'b>) -> Self {
        LockedEnvironmentProxy(
            // SAFETY: `&mut` ensures unique access.
            // "Eats" the lifetime 'b, but that's fine
            // because the bound says 'b outlives 'a and we keep 'a
            // As long as the LockedEnvironmentProxy exists
            // the Environment is exclusively borrowed
            // TODO Equivlent to experimental UnsafeCell::from_mut
            // wait for stabilization
            unsafe { 
                &mut 
                    *(value as *mut Environment as *mut UnsafeCell<Environment>)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

If I had more fields I would change vars_mut to return an aggregate struct with mutable references to all fields except `outer`.

Comment: You don't need the `UnsafeCell` here. This solution is essentially the same as the `NonNull` solution I suggested, just implemented a bit differently.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the written code is, that the `outer` pointer defines the lifetime of your child struct.

Thus every child has to live the same time as the outer environment. To define multi lifetimes for child and outer environment does not make any sense and results in different compiler errors.

Since you don't want to be able to change outer, but the value which is copyable, the best solution should be to use `Cell` which offers a zero abstraction solution to make only one part of you struct changeable but the rest immutable.

```
use std::cell::Cell;

struct Environment<'a> {
    outer: Option<&'a Environment<'a>>,
    value: Cell<i32>,
}

impl<'a> Environment<'a> {
    fn new(value: i32) -> Self {
        Self { outer: None, value: Cell::new(value) }
    }

    fn child(&'a self, value: i32) -> Environment<'a>
    {
        Self { outer: Some(self), value: Cell::new(value) }
    }
}


fn user_that_creates_child(env: &mut Environment) {
    let child_env = env.child(11);
    // Do something with the child
    child_env.outer.unwrap().value.set(8); // This should be possible
    // child_env.outer.unwrap().outer = // This shouldn't be
}

fn main() {
    let mut root_env = Environment::new(7);
    user_that_creates_child(&mut root_env);
}
```

Comment: This works if you need to store `i32`, but OP said they need a `HashMap`. With it it won't work, either if you add/remove entries or even if not.