# Lifetime of mutable reference

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I am learning Rust by implementing an interpreter for Lox, and got stuck while working on the nested environments:

```
fn evaluate(&self, env: &mut Environment) -> Result<Literal, RuntimeError> {
    let mut last_value = Literal::Null;
    let mut local_env: Environment<'_> = Environment {
        values: HashMap::new(),
        enclosing: Some(env),
    };

    for statement in self.stmts.iter() {
        let res = statement.evaluate(&mut local_env);
        match res {
            Ok(val) => {
                last_value = val;
            }
            Err(err) => {
                return Err(err);
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(last_value)
}
```

This function is to evaluate the block, thus it has its own scope where variable names live. This is what `local_env` is for. Each local_env has to know its parent (enclosing block) so if a variable name is not found in the current block, it can look it up one block above.

Environment struct is defined as:

```
pub struct Environment<'a> {
    pub values: HashMap<String, Literal>,
    pub enclosing: Option<&'a mut Environment<'a>>,
}
```

Where lifetime 'a is introduced so it satisfies the compiler, but I kinda understand what it means here: the reference to parent has to live at least as long as this particular Environment (the encompassing block includes the child block).

My issue is the error message in this setup on Some(env):

```
lifetime may not live long enough
this usage requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

Where lifetime '1 refer to the reference, '2 refer to Environment.
So, what i do now, is to introduce some lifetime for the function so '1 and '2 is the same:

```
fn evaluate<'a>(&self, env: &'a mut Environment<'a>) -> Result<Literal, RuntimeError>;
```

This results in the following error though:

```
    statement.rs(61, 5): `local_env` dropped here while still borrowed
    statement.rs(43, 13): binding `local_env` declared here
    statement.rs(41, 17): lifetime `'a` defined here
    statement.rs(49, 23): argument requires that `local_env` is borrowed for `'a`
```

```
    error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.env` as mutable more than once at a time
      --> src/interpreter.rs:28:27
       |
    13 | impl<'a> Interpreter<'a> {
       |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
    ...
    28 |             stmt.evaluate(&mut self.env);
       |             --------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
       |             |             |
       |             |             `self.env` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
       |             argument requires that `self.env` is borrowed for `'a`
```

This is where i am stuck, i was not able to understand what is the issue here. Line 61 is the end of `fn envaluate`, so local_env is dropped there, which is perfectly fine (local block variables are removed when leaving the block).
I assume the key to understand this error is the fourth line of the error message: local_env is borowed for 'a, but i just cannot see this through.

Comment: [`&'a mut Foo<'a>` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66253247/5397009). Since what you're doing is essentially a linked list of `Environment`s, I suggest you read [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: It's reading time then :). Thank you for the resources!

Comment: If somebody needs a solution, i was given one here: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/lifetime-of-mutable-reference/107385

Comment: Another relevant question: [Struct with a mutable reference to another instance of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77954494/7884305)