# Can I force a trait to be covariant?

Tags: rust, traits, covariance

Thanks to @francis-gagné 's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637911/how-can-this-instance-seemingly-outlive-its-own-parameter-lifetime#answer-42639814) to another question, I have a clearer view of how variance works. For example, a type containing a reference is covariant over its lifetime parameter, as demonstrated below.

```
struct Foo<'a> (PhantomData<&'a str>);

/// Foo is covariant over its lifetime parameter
pub fn test_foo<'a:'b, 'b:'c, 'c>() {
    let fa: Foo<'a> = Foo(PhantomData);
    let fb: Foo<'b> = Foo(PhantomData);
    let fc: Foo<'c> = Foo(PhantomData);

    let v: Vec<Foo<'b>> = vec![fa, fb]; // fc is not accepted
}
```

On the other hand a function accepting a reference (or a type containing it) is contravariant over its lifetime parameter.

```
struct Bar<'a> (PhantomData<fn(&'a str)>);

/// Bar is contravariant over its lifetime parameter
pub fn test_bar<'a:'b, 'b:'c, 'c>() {
    let ba: Bar<'a> = Bar(PhantomData);
    let bb: Bar<'b> = Bar(PhantomData);
    let bc: Bar<'c> = Bar(PhantomData);

    let v: Vec<Bar<'b>> = vec![bb, bc]; // ba is not accepted
}
```

Finally, a *trait* with a lifetime parameter is invariant over its lifetime parameter.

```
pub trait Baz<'a> {}

impl<'a> Baz<'a> for () {}

/// Baz is invariant over its lifetime parameter
pub fn test_baz<'a:'b, 'b:'c, 'c>() {
    let za: Box<dyn Baz<'a>> = Box::new(());
    let zb: Box<dyn Baz<'b>> = Box::new(());
    let zc: Box<dyn Baz<'c>> = Box::new(());

    let v: Vec<Box<dyn Baz<'b>>> = vec![zb]; // za and zx are not accepted
}
```

That makes sense, because the trait could be implemented both by a covariant and a contravariant type, as illustrated below.

```
impl<'a> Baz<'a> for Foo<'a> {}
impl<'a> Baz<'a> for Bar<'a> {}
```

My question is: can I force a trait to be covariant over its lifetime parameter? I would expect a marker trait such as:

```
trait Baz<'a>: Covariant<'a> {}
```

that would make it illegal to implement that trait with a contravariant type, and allow `za` to be a member of the vector `v` in the `test_baz` function above.

Of course, being able to do the opposite (force a trait to be contravariant) could be useful as well...

[Examples in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d26eee2aca9bf88f38b2281b0f8e423c)

Comment: Here's a [post summarizing all variance rules in Rust](https://medium.com/@kennytm/variance-in-rust-964134dd5b3e). Somebody may find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You can express "a value that implements `Baz<'x>` for *any* `'x`":

```
pub fn test_baz<'a:'b, 'b:'c, 'c>() {
    let za: Box<dyn for<'x> Baz<'x>> = Box::new(());
    let zb: Box<dyn for<'x> Baz<'x>> = Box::new(());
    let zc: Box<dyn for<'x> Baz<'x>> = Box::new(());

    let v: Vec<Box<dyn for<'x> Baz<'x>>> = vec![za, zb, zc];
}
```

But you can't (as of Rust 1.31) write `Box<dyn for<'x: 'b> Baz<'x>>`, and even if you could, that syntax would only work for lifetimes; it wouldn't let you express covariance over type parameters.

Comment: I wanted to add more elaboration, or make a helpful suggestion, but it's hard to tell what exactly the question is going for, so this is the simple answer.  If you have concrete code that needs a feature like this, I'd be interested to see a sample, and maybe then I could make a suggestion.

Comment: My problem is quite complex, it is hard to summarize it, and I'm not even sure that a covariant trait is the solution I need... I was mainly trying to get a better understanding if the whole picture.

Answer (score 5):

I found a workaround. Rather than marking the trait as covariant (which, as @trentcl noted, is not possible in Rust 1.31), I made the type implement the trait for all lifetimes smaller than its own:

```
impl<'a:'b, 'b> Baz<'b> for Foo<'a> {}
```

That way, I can use instances of `Foo<'b>` *and* `Foo<'a>` whenever a `Bar<'b>` is required:

```
pub fn test_baz<'a:'b, 'b:'c, 'c>() {
    let fa: Foo<'a> = Foo(PhantomData);
    let fb: Foo<'b> = Foo(PhantomData);
    let fc: Foo<'c> = Foo(PhantomData);

    let v: Vec<&dyn Baz<'b>> = vec![&fa, &fb]; // &fc is not accepted
}
```

Of course, that requires every implementer of the trait to follow this pattern, so it is not as powerful as marking the trait *itself* as covariant. But it can do the trick in some situations.

[Example in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=63002cb9000dc3191ec622d1af8def3d)