# Why does it work to pass `&mut Vec<&'static str>` to a function which takes `&mut Vec<&'a str>`?

Tags: rust

In "Rust for Rustaceans", it says

> Some types are *invariant*, which means that you must provide exactly the given type. `&mut T` is an example of this - if a function takes a `&mut Vec<&'a str>`, you cannot pass it a `&mut Vec<&'static str>`. That is, `&mut T` is invariant in `T`. If you could, the function could put a short-lived string inside the `Vec`, which the caller would then continue using, thinking that it were a `Vec<&'static str>` and thus that the contained string were `'static`!

Sounds reasonable. But then, why does the following compile?

```rust
fn my_func<'a>(_a: &mut Vec<&'a str>) {
    println!("here");
}


fn main() {
    let inner: &'static str = "foo";
    let mut b: Vec<&'static str> = vec![inner];
    my_func(&mut b);
}
```

Does anyone have an example demonstrating what the book talks about?

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639814) for an explanation on lifetime covariance (and contravariance), which makes it possible for a parameter of type `&'_ mut Vec<&'a str>` accept a `&'_ mut Vec<&'static str>`.

Answer (score 3):

The example compiles because at the callsite, `'a` can be instantiated with `'static`. Remember: it's a generic parameter, `'a` is just a name we are giving *some* lifetime at the callsite.

What the book is talking about is an interaction between multiple lifetimes. For example:

```rust
fn my_func<'a>(_a: &mut Vec<&'a str>, _b: &'a str) {}

fn main() {
    let inner: &'static str = "foo";
    let mut a: Vec<&'static str> = vec![inner];
    let b = "bar".to_string();
    my_func(&mut a, &b);
    // error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
}
```

In this example, we have the original argument for `my_func`, but also another argument *with the same lifetime* `'a`. At the callsite, we have a vector with a static string, but also a `String` that is local to the `main` method. Now, we cannot instantiate `'a` as `'static`, because of the second argument.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I can't get my head round the fact that if `_a` was just `& Vec` instead of `&mut Vec` then it would compile

Comment: I'll to explain. With `my_func<'a>(_a: &mut Vec<&'a str>, _b: &'a str)`, then when `&mut a` and `&b` are passed to it, then because `&mut T` is invariant in `T`, then `&mut 'static` is passed to it, and `b` is attempted to be coerced to the same lifetime, but that's not possible, it doesn't live long enough. However, with `my_func<'a>(_a: & Vec<&'a str>, _b: &'a str)`, then `&T` isn't invariant, so `&a` and `&b` can be passed to the function with the same lifetime as that of `b`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can pass a reference to `Vec<&'static str>` in place of `Vec<&'a str>` there, since `Vec` is covariant in its type argument (`Vec<A> <: Vec<B>` if `A <: B`), shared references are also covariant in their lifetime (`&'a X <: &'b X` if `'a <: 'b`), and of course `'static <: 'a` for any lifetime. That's the rule-based explanation.

Comment: You can also think about the capabilities granted to the function. 1) Read capability: it is safe to choose a shorter lifetime than the one of the passed-in reference, because when the function reads from it, the reference is guaranteed to be live. 2) Write capability: the situation is reversed. The function can safely write something that lives *at least* as long as the declared lifetime (so that the callsite can still use the result). Shared references give read-only capabilities (-> covariant), mutable references give read *and* write capabilities (-> co- *and* contravariant, so invariant).